When publishing an ImageMosaic, there is a failure to properly recognize Null Values for multiple rasters and no data area's gray value is 0
I am attempting to publish a batch of rasters as an ImageMosaic WMS service, with each individual raster having a No Data value set to 255. The raster details(gdalinfo tool get) are illustrated in the image below:
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = Band_1
  Min=0.000 Max=100.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=100.000, Mean=63.779, StdDev=20.227
  NoData Value=255
  Overviews: 843x432, 422x216
  Metadata:
    BandName=Band_1
    RepresentationType=ATHEMATIC
    STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=409.1250615978853
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=100
    STATISTICS_MEAN=63.779409544259
    STATISTICS_MEDIAN=66.000000
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
    STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=20.226840128846

I am planning to publish a single raster as an ImageMosaic WMS service, where the Null Values are recognizable as 255. This Null Value setting can be observed in the Layer Properties interface, as depicted in the image below:

When publishing multiple rasters as an ImageMosaic WMS service, the Null Values are recognized as 0, as illustrated in the following image:

When previewing the map in OpenLayer's Preview, clicking on areas with no data still returns a pixel value, which is 0. Furthermore, when filtering the data using CQL to only display one dataset, the grayscale value for areas lacking data remains at 0, as shown in the figure below:

I am curious as to why there is a discrepancy in the recognition of null values between multiple and single rasters when publishing as an ImageMosaic WMS service. Additionally, why does clicking on the no-data regions of the ImageMosaic's WMS service return a grayscale value?
Can someone help me?
